# How to test a function in PSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/05/11/postgresql-plpgsql.html

But it fails when I get to the try command:

```
mattswheels=# try=% select fib(8);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "try"
LINE 1: try=% select fib(8);
        ^
```

How can I test out my newly created function?

Comment: `try=%` in that article is a psql prompt like `mattswheels=#` in your example. Just skip it.

Comment: Yep that was it, duh, thanks. Feel free to make this an answer and I'll select it.